# Swagger ui endpoints are duplicated

Tags: swagger, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am using the wonderful project [api platform](https://api-platform.com/). I create my entities and endpoints are working like a charm.

Right now, I want to configure the documentation because endpoints are showed duplicated. For example, I have a relation 1 to N between two entities and on documentation which is automatically generated via swagger the endpoints are duplicated.

For example, in this relation between competition and event, I have the same endpoint *[/competitions/{id}/events]* for each entity.

[image: Duplicated endpoints.]

Do you know if is there any way to show endpoints once? It is not a big deal, but I want to keep the documentation as clean as possible.

**Edited**

Competition:

```
/**
 * Competitions able to request.
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *              attributes={
 *                  "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}}
 *              },
 *              collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *              itemOperations={"get"}
 *     )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

    class Competition
{
/**
 * @var int The competition Id
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"read","write"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string Name of the competition
 *
 * @ORM\Column
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Groups({"read","write"})
 *
 */
public $name = '';



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="competitions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ApiSubresource(maxDepth=1)
 * @Groups("write")
 */
public $events;
```

Event:

```
/**
 * Available event
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *              attributes={
 *                  "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}},
 *                  "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"write"}}
 *              },
 *              collectionOperations={"get", "post"},
 *              itemOperations={
 *                  "get"}
 *  )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Event
{
/**
 * @var int The entity Id
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"read", "write"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string The name of the event available.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Groups({"read","write"})
 */
public $name = '';


/**
 * @var string Start date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Groups({"read","write"})
 */
public $start;



/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Competition", inversedBy="events")
 * @Groups({"write"})
 */

public $competitions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to disable some "operations":

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Book.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * ...
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"get"},
 *     itemOperations={"get"}
 *     )
 */
class Book
{
    // ...
}
```

To hide/show what you want.

Comment: Yes, I did it but it didn't work.  I need to show the operation just in one endpoint. I mean, the operation should be enabled  but I don't want to show it twice in documentation.

It is just to have a clear API.

Comment: please can you copy/paste your annotations?